# How to find a JsonElement at any level in Json

Tags: java, json, gson

I would like to read the "messages" element that can come at any level of the Json structure.
**Sample Json**

```
{
  "Order": {
    "array": [
      {
        "messages": "value"
      },{
        "element1":"value",
        "element2":"value"
      }
    ],
    "Object1":"value",
    "Object2":{
      "element1":"value",
      "messages":"value"
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please suggest how can i read messages section in java. Here this particular element can come at level or any object in the json.

Comment: `json` is a generic concept. Please, express which platform, programming language or/and DBMS you use along with it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using Java and gson library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSONObject to play with any level but you should know the element key of the level .

```
    import  org.json.JSONObject

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject( "{\"extensions\":{\"car\":{\"color\":\"blue\",\"ageInYears\":10},\"favoriteNumber\":3.14159265359,\"isLucky\":true}}");

    jsonObj.put("child1Key1", "someValue");

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    System.out.println("jsonObj"+jsonObj);
    jsonObj.remove("child1Key1" );
   
     System.out.println("after adding jsonObj"+jsonObj);


    jsonObj
            .getJSONObject("extensions")
            .getJSONObject("car").put("ageInYears","100");

    System.out.println("after update jsonObj"+jsonObj);


    System.out.println("after remove  "+jsonObj
            .getJSONObject("extensions")
            .getJSONObject("car").remove("ageInYears"));;

    System.out.println("after remove jsonObj"+jsonObj);


    System.out.println("after remove  "+jsonObj
            .getJSONObject("extensions").remove("isLucky"));
            //.getJSONObject("car").remove("ageInYears"));;


    System.out.println("after remove-1 jsonObj"+jsonObj);
```